# How to generate addresses in PHP

Tags: address, php, address-generation

I need some PHP code to generate bitcoin addresses from a given public key.

I can only find algorithms to generate addresses from the master private key but according to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses
the private key is not required at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use BitWasp Bitcoin-php library
https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php

```
<?php
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory;

$network = Bitcoin::getNetwork();
$privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory::create(true);
$publicKey = $privateKey->getPublicKey();
$address = $publicKey->getAddress(); // returns AddressInterface
echo $address->getAddress($network); // prints address for $network as string
```

If you want to create Bitcoin address from Public key string [check documentation](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php/tree/master/doc) for **Factory classes**

or newer versions:

```
<?php
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Address\AddressCreator;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\KeyToScript\Factory\P2pkhScriptDataFactory; 

$network = Bitcoin::getNetwork();
$privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory::create(true);
$publicKey = $privateKey->getPublicKey();

$addrCreator = new AddressCreator();
$factory = new P2pkhScriptDataFactory();
$scriptPubKey = $factory->convertKey($publicKey)->getScriptPubKey();
$address = $addrCreator->fromOutputScript($scriptPubKey); // returns AddressInterface
echo $address->getAddress($network); // prints address for $network as string
```

Comment: This answer still uses a private key and is not purely public key based, like asked for.

Comment: You can do PublicKeyFactory::fromHex and avoid using a private key.
For newer versions, getAddress was removed, see this example https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php/blob/9e535f04665ba22ba2b8b63f371ec50d2e7eabb8/examples/addresstypes.script.php#L16-18

Answer (score 2):

Full instruction based on response of @Farghaly: **Ubuntu 16**

Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install php-bcmath php-gmp
composer require bitwasp/bitcoin
```

And then in fiel `app.php`

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Address;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory;

$network = Bitcoin::getNetwork();

$privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory::create(true);
$publicKey = $privateKey->getPublicKey();
$address = $publicKey->getAddress();
```

Comment: vendor/autoload.php
where can i find this file?

Comment: @makasci I believe it is automatically generated by composer when you run `composer install`